# How can I convert timezone return value to desired string format

Tags: python, django, datetime-format

How can I convert timezone.now() to desired string format.

For example, I need to convert the following datetime value

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 8, 54, 51, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

to something like this

```
Thu 13 Nov 2014, 08:54:51 AM
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 13, 8, 54, 51).strftime('%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M:%S %p')
```